# How to see the database name of each physical Mdf file?

Tags: sql-server, database, mdf, data-recovery, file-recovery

I formatted my pc, so I lost a lot of MDF files(Databases), using a program I was able to recover a lot of .mdf files, the thing is that they have a different name.

I have a list of mdf files, for example:

folder: MDFiles
Content: f324324234.mdf, f908908445.mdf..etc.

My question is, How do I get the database name of each .mdf file.

I KNOW IT CAN BE DONE, because I downloaded a program(Systools) and it does it,
the only problem is that I'd have to do it one at a time, and I want to see all because I have more than 150 .mdf files.

PS. I ask this question here, because this is a situation that other programmers might have had before.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software/OS tech support.

Comment: .mdf files are Microsoft SQL Server Database files that are used for Programmers.

Comment: and spaghetti is food eaten by programmers, yet you don't see cooking questions here. you're not asking for programming help. you're asking for what boils down to systems administration/recovery, which is offtopic.

Comment: If this is not a question suitible here, why do I have tags that suits my specific problem?, I guess that if this wasn't an appropiate here, StackOverflow wouldn't give me those tags.

There's a tag called mdf, and I'm asking about mdf files, there's a tag called data-Recovery, and this question is about that, there's a tag called file-recovery, and this question is about that, there's a tag called database and this question is about that too.

Comment: Tags are tags. Just because it exists doesn't mean it'll apply to YOUR particular situation. You're not asking about code, you don't have ANY code, you're asking how to recover a database, and THAT'S NOT PROGRAMMING.

Comment: Anger management isn't programming either, though some programmers could benefit from it :)

Comment: I'm not asking "how to recover a database", please learn to read. I asked how I get the database name for each .mdf file, which can be done programming, this is not right, because this question is about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE ('C:\WOOPS\XXXX.MDF', X)
```

Where `X` is 2 for the DB name and 3 for the original file details.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day